# Tableau 8.1 Linking Dashboard with URL to open in the same explorer page

Tags: url, tableau-api

I have created a **Landing Page** in Tableau that links several reports open to one home screen using a **Dashboard**. The idea for the dashboard came from:

http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-table-contents-navigate-other-dashboards

I have placed a **Workbook** onto a **Dashboard** and created a URL action. Once the user clicks on the link it should take them to the link provided.

The issue is, when the user clicks on the link, it opens a **new** tab within the browser. I do not want it to do this. My Landing page goes through several pages, so imagine the user frustration when opening a new tab every click.

Can anyone advise how I can add a Action URL that will open in the same tab the user is currently in.

I have checked for several solution online, this one being the most promising, but it still fails to work for my solution:

http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/howto/set-server-views-to-open-links-in-same-window

Comment: Have you tried using a Web page object on the dashboard that is populated based on what the user selects?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by adding a new dashboard, creating a link to that dashboard from the Landing Page. On the dashboard I placed a Web page object as mentioned above.

I would also mention that if you want the object to open in the same screen you Need to include tabs when publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of the URL you are putting in the action.  ?:embed=y&:linktarget=_self